# itemDoubleClicked signal for subclass of QListWidgetItem

Tags: c++, qt, signals, qlistwidget, slots

I have tried everything I know of (which admittedly isn't very much) and searched google for about an hour but I just can't figure this out.

I have a class called `PlaceHolder`, which inherits from `QListWidgetItem`. I want to be able to register double clicks on this, so I tried using the signal `itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem*)` on the `QListWidget`. However, when I do that, I need a slot that has the same arguments. This would not be a problem if I didn't need to access the functions/variables of the `PlaceHolder` that was clicked, but I do.

If there's anything else you need to know to help me then please feel free to ask. Thank you for any time and effort you spent on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit unclear on your question. Is the problem that you have a QListWidgetItem* instead of a PlaceHolder*?

Try:

```
void MyWidget::handleDoubleClickSlot(QListWidgetItem* item)
{
    PlaceHolder* placeHolderItem = qobject_cast<PlaceHolder*>(item);

    if (placeHolderItem == NULL)
    {
        // oops, not a PlaceHolder item
        return;
    }

    placeHolderItem->myAwesomePlaceHolderMethod();
}
```

As shown, it will return NULL if the item is somehow not a PlaceHolder object.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I get the error message: `no matching function call to 'qobject_cast(QListWidgetItem*&)'`. What part have I messed up on?

Comment: Hmm, did you enter it as above with angle brackets first around "PlaceHolder*", then parenthesis afterward? You need "#include <QObject>" included from something, but in widgets something should have certainly included that...

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the parentheses around item. My bad.